# Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 3 to TIMESTAMP in glassfish

Tags: datetime, jdbc, glassfish

Getting error Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 3 to TIMESTAMP in glassfish.

I am already set jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.23:3307/training?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull on my JDBC Connection Pool Properties.

What's wrong?

Comment: some code could be usefull...

Answer (score 0):

Possible Reasons & Solutions -

1. Your Column 3 is of type `DATETIME` & you are trying to operate `Timestamp` on it.
2. In hibernate.cfg.xml:
   convertToNull

In hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

mysql-ds.xml file for JBOSS as:

```
<connection-property name="zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</connection-property>
```

Comment: Am using glassfish not JBOSS.